# Function wont return a value?

Tags: php, function

I am trying to set a variable in a function so that when the function is called, it would provide the script with a variable value to inform the page that the function was called.  This works just displaying a message:

```
function MyMessage($display_message)
{
    echo $display_message;
}
```

That works fine, so when I call up:

```
MyMessage("Updated Database!");
```

that works too np.  The problem is that the function displays this message before the header file in some pages since the header is at the bottom of the page before it is called.  Is it possible to make it like:

```
function MyMessage($display_message)
{

    $function_ran = 1;

    echo $display_message;

    return $function_ran;

}
```

Then in the script if I display

```
if ( $function_ran != 1 )
{
    include("header.php");
}
```

That way it only displays the header if the function is not ran.  The problem is that the $function_ran value is not returned when the function is called.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use globals, you need to store the result of the function:

```
$function_ran = MyMessage("Updated Database!");
if ( $function_ran != 1 )
{
  include("header.php");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that first by adding header to the function but the paths and other complex codes in the header caused a ton of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Make `$function_ran` a global and ensure you use the global version in the function.

```
$function_ran = 0;

# stuff

function MyMessage($display_message)
{
    global $function_ran;
    $function_ran = 1;
    echo $display_message;
}
```

Comment: Ah good idea, I always used globals to pull variables from outside of the function never thought of that.

Comment: Weird its not working.  The value still remains 0 even when the function is called.

Comment: Are you calling the function before or after the `$function_ran = 0;` assignment?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the return of the function you have to assign the return to a variable like:

```
$function_ran = MyMessage("Updated Database!");
```

Of course, it would be possible to make `$function_ran` global, but than you don't have to use the return.

I would definitely go for the assigning of the return value, because that is more transparent and the better programming style.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking before calling the function, the function could use a static variable to avoid doing its work twice:

```
function MyMessage($display_message) {
    static $function_ran = false;

    if ($function_ran) {
        return;
    }

    $function_ran = true;
    echo $display_message;
}
```

Comment: So weird, I created a separate file as a test and it works, but it doesnt work on my main script what could be the conflict be?

Comment: Without seeing your script, it's impossible for me to guess what you did wrong.

Comment: The only difference is that the function is called on a POST, and the function is included in another file thats it.

Comment: None of that should make any difference. My guess is you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I think I know what the problem is.  Most of the time when I call this function I have an exit() after it perhaps it is closing before submitting that value

Comment: If you're exiting, then you're not calling the function twice, so what's the problem? Are you expecting the variable to persist between different invocations of the script? Only session variables and cookies do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sessions, you should use session handler and use it,you can set a session for return value of this function.

Comment: I may just do it the harder way and pass the value through thefunction like    MyMessage($display_message, $function_ran)

Comment: you can create a format for some session: `_FUNC_class_functionname_`

Comment: Or clean naming, you can choose two name: `_OBJ_CLASS_FUNCTIONNAME_` for `methods` and `_FUNC_FUNCTIONNAME_` for your function. Even you can add your files to name of your sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the flag in a global, but to modify the global variable from the function you need  to use the global keyword.

Something like:

```
$function_ran = 0;

function MyMessage($display_message) {
  global $function_ran;

  $function_ran = 1;
  echo $display_message;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have done exactly that it is not working so weird. I will write up a blank file to test it and see why and then try to apply it to my main script